# Split a string with '|' char

Tags: php, split

I want to split following string with char "|" but I got following error, Any ideas?

error:

```
Warning: split() [function.split]: REG_EMPTY in E:\AppServ\www\admin\panelActions\editApplication.php on line 39
```

string :

```
|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_0.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_1.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_2.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_3.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_4.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_5.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_6.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_7.jpg
```

code :

```
$__screenShots = split("|", $requestRow['appImages']);
```

Comment: You're using regex split? Why not just `explode()` it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Form PHP DOC about [`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Try

```
$string = '|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_0.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_1.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_2.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_3.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_4.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_5.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_6.jpg|../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_7.jpg' ;
var_dump(explode("|", $string));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_0.jpg' (length=67)
  2 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_1.jpg' (length=67)
  3 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_2.jpg' (length=67)
  4 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_3.jpg' (length=67)
  5 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_4.jpg' (length=67)
  6 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_5.jpg' (length=67)
  7 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_6.jpg' (length=67)
  8 => string '../../filesBank/_screenshots/com.beem.project.beem_screenshot_7.jpg' (length=67)
```

*** If you still want to use `split` ***

This is the way yo use it

```
$string = split("[|]", $string);
var_dump($string);
```

You can getting `split() [function.split]: REG_EMPTY` becasue you tried to use it like this

```
   $string = split("|", $string);
```

Comment: When I try to use your code my array length changed to 9, Why?

Comment: @iSun the first array is empty .. there must be because the line begins with the separator `|`

Comment: if you want it to return 8 use `array_filter` it would remove empty array from the list

Answer (score 2):

If you use a function that is about some regular expression flavor, you should actually understand that you are using a special character here:

> `|` --- The choice (aka alternation or set union) operator matches either the expression before or the expression after the operator. For example, **`abc|def` matches `"abc"` or `"def"`**.

([POSIX Basic Regular Expressions Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions))

What you want to do is to take the literal `|` character, so you need to escape it:

```
split('\\|', ...)
```

Take care that the split function is deprecated (POSIX flavoured regular expression functions) and that with `explode` you can achieve something quite similar in your case. If not, use `preg_split`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explode() function - nearly the same

Comment: `explode()` is not nearly the same.

Comment: In this case? Exactly same.Additionly, split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: `split()` is deprecated. and this is sufficient to do not use it.

Comment: preg_split() is more similar to split()... Good to know it when fixing  deprecated code.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, [*the function*] split() [*states that the*] REG_[*is*]EMPTY in [your file] E:\AppServ\www\admin\panelActions\editApplication.php on line 39.

So, don't use an empty regular expression.

Comment: This is a great answer!; s/answer/comment;